# (EclipseLink) JPA ignores custom table for @TableGenerator

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I'm working with a database in which every table must be prefixed (company policy).

My Entities have the following annotations for the Id

```
@TableGenerator(name = "x_gen", table = "pfx_sequence", pkColumnName = "sequence", valueColumnName = "counter", pkColumnValue = "table_x_seq")  
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "x_gen")
```

where "x" is replaced for every table.

The problem is that when EclipseLink tries to update the table it goes for the default values (table SEQUENCE with columns SEQ_NAME and SEQ_COUNT)

```
Error Code: 1146
Call: UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?
        bind => [2 parameters bound]
Query: DataModifyQuery(name="pe_genk" sql="UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?")
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'my_schema.SEQUENCE' doesn't exist
```

any idea where to look?

Thanks

Comment: Stack trace and logs should help. EclipseLink logs should show what it is processing when it looks at your entity and the sequencing on it, as it seems it isn't finding or using your annotation.

Comment: I was just looking at that. Thanks, the problem was a misspelling in the name of the generator in one of the entities. I guess I was (I am) tired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a misspelling in one of my entities.

eg

```
@TableGenerator(name = "x_gen" [...])
@GeneratedValue(generator="x_genn" [...])
```